# How can I pass credentials to a UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have an issue where I am displaying some HTML in a Web View (locally stored) and it is pulling images from a secure server.  Normally, in order to view that image by itself in a desktop browser, or even the built in Safari Browser, I get prompted for my Username / Password.

For example, say I have the following HTML:

```
<img src="http://mysecureserver.example.com/image.png">
```

If I navigate to `http://mysecureserver.example.com/image.png` in a browser, I get prompted for my username / password.

However, when I display the full HTML in a `UIWebView`, the rest of the HTML renders properly, but that image does not show up and no errors are thrown.

Therefore, I would simply like to know if I can pass my Username/Password to the Web View so that the container is authenticated and, in theory, now be able to view the image.

Any ideas??

Thank you in advance!!!

***also, please note that***:

The iPad is already set up to be on a VPN.  Even with the iPad set up on the VPN no image is being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this: http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~watrous/user-pass-url.html?

Comment: That worked, thank you!! .. we're researching to see how secure this idea is as we are concerned that a plain-text password is being passed in the query string.

Comment: you could maybe urlencode it for a trivial obfuscation (I haven't tested this), but if compromising the password is a serious issue, I don't know of a way it can be kept secure from a determined hacker. even if you handle the authentication in a hidden manner from your app, the password will have to be kept in your app in such a way that you can decode it; and so it can be found and read by anyone who has the app.

Comment: To update you on what's been going on, I contacted Apple directly and there response was to file a bug report...  They suggested exactly what you suggested in your original post as a quick work-around, but we are still pretty worried about sending over UN/PW over with obfuscation and or plain text.  Will update you as things progress.  Thank you again!